# How to change values in JSON file during runtime?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to change JSON files values during runtime.

I have multiple locators in a JSON file those have id and/or xpath, I plan to find an element during runtime(Java) by xpath then change the value and again search for that element that it's xpath value changed:

JSON file:

> "SERIES": {
>      "xpath": "//*[@text='SERIES']"
>    },
>
> "MOVIE": {
>      "xpath": "//*[@text='MOVIE']"
>    },
>    ...

Then in runtime in java code I want to find the element MOVIE by this xpath then change the xpath to

> "MOVIE": {
>      "xpath": "//*[@text='Spider Man']"
>    },

Then search again for MOVIE element (that it's value already changed).

The challenge is how to change the value in JSON file at runtime.

I found this solution:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#expressions-language-ref
>   6.5.18 Expression templating

But it will break my code as we have some value that uses # and causes confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution :) I put it here in case if someone have same question:

Solution is very easy if we handle it from Java side, compare to Spring Reference Expression:

You need to parse the locator in Java like this:
In json file Change locator from:

```
"MOVIE": { "xpath": "//*[@text='MOVIE']" }
```

to:

```
"MOVIE": { "xpath": "//*[@text='$NEWTITLE$']" }
```

In java code parse the locator:

```
String xpathParam = locator.getXpathValue();
String xpath = String.format(xpathParam, "").replace("$NEWTITLE$", "Spider Man");
```